# why the react app did not render anything in the web UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Today I write a react demo app, now I found the web UI did not render anything when start the app. this is my `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import store  from './store/store';
import routes from './routes/routes';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      {routes}
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

and this is the `routes.js` file:

```
import { Route,Routes,BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../page/index/App';

const routes = (
    <BrowserRouter>        
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={App}/>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default routes;
```

and this is the `App.tsx` file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I run this app, the web UI did not render the Hello World. am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this problem? this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "ai-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-rewire-alias": "^1.1.7",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start --config-overrides ./src/config/build/config-overrides.js",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build --config-overrides path/to/config-overrides.js",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --config-overrides path/to/config-overrides.js",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

this is my store.js :

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../common/combineReducer';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

and this is the rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import chat from '../reducer/chat/ChatReducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    chat
})

export default rootReducer;
```

this is the chatReducer(I think it is not using the reducer now):

```
const initState = {
    article: {}
};

const ChatReducer = (state=initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_ARTICLE":
            state = action.article;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
};

export default ChatReducer;
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to the store.tsx/store.js file you have?

Comment: I have pasted the store file.

Comment: Does your HTML have a root element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code, issue is with router configuration. You have used older version 4 of react-router-dom syntax and you have used version 6 as a dependency. So you have to adjust the router code as follows.

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../page/index/App";

const routes = (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<App />} />
  </Routes>
);

export default routes;
```

As you can see the `component` is no longer supported instead use `element`. Refet the [React Router Dom Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)

A working sample code from your code at https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-haze-yiitnq